# how to process a 2D array in assembly

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, multidimensional-array

I have been reading a book on assembly language programming, and it has a practice problem that I can't seem to figure out.
The problem says that given the function prototype

```
void multiply2D (unsigned char image[numRows][numCols], int numRows, int numCols,
    int factor)
```

I should find a way to write the function in assembly which multiplys the entire array by the `factor` without using a nested loop.

I understand that a 2D array will decay into a single linear array in assembly, however I can't figure out an algorithm to indicate when to stop (i.e. reached end of array). I thought about simply multiplying  the columns and the rows to get the overall size, however it states that the size of multiplying the rows by the columns may not fit into an integer.

Comment: maybe nested loop....

Comment: sorry forgot the part where it states that I should not use nested loops.

Comment: Use whatever type can fit the entire addressable space then. `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` probably. On 32 bit, for example, unsigned int should be sufficient since you can't address more than 4GB anyway.

Comment: You just need to keep 3 variables in 3 registers, the pointer to current element, i, j. Step 1: Multiply current number. Step 2: Increment i and advance pointer. If i = numCols then set i to 0 and increment j. Step 3: Go to step 1, unless j = numRows.

Comment: @nhahtdh that is morally equivalent to a nested loop which the OP said he can't use.

Comment: Use unsigned QWORD or TWORD (binary coded decimal) to store the multiplied value?

Comment: I can only use a 32-bit assembler, so I can't use QWORD

Comment: @TimSeguine: Yes, it is equivalent to a nested loop. How else would you loop through the array if you are not allowed to multiply the number of rows & columns for the size?

Comment: @user3769877 You *can* use the QWORD datatype in 32 bit assembly. But the information about your CPU and data with is essential. So you should add it to the question.

Comment: @nhahtdh don't really know.  Both restrictions seem artificial and pointless.

Comment: I understand exactly what you mean, however, I think the purpose of this problem is to demonstrate understanding of multidimensional arrays at the low-level

Comment: Would you count recursion as a doubly nested loop?  Or having a called procedure that multiplies a 1D matrix and a second procedure that uses it to perform the 2D matrix multiplication?  The practice problem may be about stack management and parameter passing, not the model used to implement array in memory, which may not be contiguous blocks like C-style arrays.

Comment: I'd say compute the address of the end of the array.  Then loop until your pointer reaches the end pointer.  Of course, the computation is going to involve a multiply, but you can use pointer sized values to do the math.

Comment: Hint: the x86 MUL instruction will produce a 64-bit product  in EAX:EDX. [Even if that weren't the case, the industrious programmer would write his own 64 bit multiply].  So  OP *can* compute the product and get a size; and he can step through the array multiplying by the factor.  He just needs to subtract one from a 64 bit value in EAX:EDX (see SUB and SBC instructions) and stop when the result goes negative (may need to adjust initial value to avoid off-by-one).  [The doubly-nested loop would be faster. But then so would using various vector ops]

Comment: If the `rows * cols` doesn't fit into an `int`, how about fitting it into a `size_t`? It *has to* fit into `size_t`, otherwise you couldn't even index into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2D array is infact a complete linear array with a size `numRows * numCols` in this case. Therefore you must perform a 32x32=64 multiplication where the 64-bit answer will be in some register somewhere (Look at the [assembler reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) for the instruction you need).

In psuedo-code you need to:

```
reg_64 rsize = numRows * numCols
reg_64 count = 0

while( count < rsize )
    image[count] *= factor
```

An i7 has 64bit register access, so you have access to a 64-bit type.

If you're really struggling you can ofcourse write it in C and compile it, and then disassemble it with objdump to see how the compiler solves the problem! It may not be the most efficient, but it will at least be an answer!

Comment: yeah I know my CPU has 64-bit, is just that the book i'm reading focuses more on 32-bit for the sake of simplicity. I ended up doing it like how Tim Seguine suggested and put it in an unsigned int since in 32 bit you won't be able to address more than 2^32 bytes of memory anyway. but your idea for disassembling a c program was interesting as well.